# Opening and writing to a new window from a Google Chrome extension sandbox page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

(Cross posted [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-extensions/n3BvWwSJxAw/discussion))

Hi,

I have a sandboxed page (specified in my manifest) which is loaded into an iframe in my extension's background page. From within my sandboxed page, I'd like to open a new window and write to it, i.e.:

var win = window.open(); win.document.write('<p&gtHello!</p>');

This works from my extension's background page and from regular web pages, but when invoked from either content scripts or my sandboxed page, the window opens, but I cannot access the win object (it's defined, but empty---console.log outputs "Window {}").

I assume this is due to same-origin policies (with every window being given a uinque-origin within the sandboxed environment). However, since the window opens an about:blank page, I'm confused why this would matter.

Is this a feature? Is there a parameter I can add to my manifest to avoid this?  And does anyone know of work-arounds that don't involve using postMessage back to my background page? My ideal solution is to have my sandboxed script open a new window and interact with it directly, not with message passing.

I can provide a full example if necessary, but I'm hoping someone might just know off the top of their head. I'm running Chrome 24.0.1312.57 on Mac and 24.0.1312.68 on Ubuntu if that helps.

Thanks,

Hank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the cross-post [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/topic/chromium-extensions/n3BvWwSJxAw/discussion), the issue is indeed that the opened window is given a unique origin. This was intentional as the members of the standards working group (SWG) felt that it would be more secure to not make an exception for about:blank pages where they inherit the sandbox's origin.

However, to get around this issue, at least for my purposes, I can use the following method. First, forget sandboxing. This workaround uses an iframe embedded in a background page with the src url set to `data:text/html,...`. This gives a unique origin to the iframe so it's no longer in extension space. That means eval can be used and chrome apis cannot be accessed. Unlike in a sandbox, windows opened from the iframe share that same origin as the iframe, allowing created windows to be accessed. For example:

In a background html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="background.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <iframe id="myframe"></iframe>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

In background.js:

```
...
document.getElementById('myframe').setAttribute('src', 'data:text/html,'+ 
    encodeURI('<html><head>'+
    '<script src='+chrome.extension.getURL('jquery.js')+'></script>'+
    '<script src='+chrome.extension.getURL('myscript.js')+'></script>'+
    ...
    '</head><body></body></html>'
));
...
```

In myscript.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    // To receive messages from background.js.
    window.addEventListener('message', function(e){ ... } );

    // To send messages to background.js.
    parent.postMessage({...}, '*');

    // To open AND ACCESS a window.
    var win = window.open();
    win.document.write('Hello'); // Fails in sandbox, works here.

    // Eval code, if you want. Can't do this from an extension
    // page loaded normally unless you allow eval in your manifest.
    // Here, it's okay!
    eval( 'var x = window.open(); x.document.write("Hi!")' );

    // No chrome apis.
    chrome.log( chrome.extension ); // -> undefined
    chrome.log( chrome.windows ); // -> undefined

    // No direct access to background page (e.g., parent).
    chrome.log( parent ); // -> Window with no properties.
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Content scripts, by definition, are part of external regular web pages you load so I'm not really sure how your script could work on a "regular web page" but not the content script. Do you mean the code works when you embed it in your own pages, but not in other pages via the content script?

Regardless, if the script is working properly from your background page, you could always try messaging. (more here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)

Script for your sandbox/contentscript:

```
//send message to background page
chrome.extension.sendMessage({todo: "newWindow"});
```

In background page:

```
//create a listener
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender) {   
    if (request.todo === "newWindow") {
    //do your stuff here
        var win = window.open(); win.document.write('<p&gtHello!</p>');
    }
  });
```

Comment: What I meant is that, ignoring the extension altogether, if you write a web page that does `var win = window.open(); win.document.write('&lt;p&gt;Hello!&lt;/p&gt;')`, it works as expected. However, from within a sandbox in my extension, that's not the case. Back over in my cross post, someone from the chrome team confirmed the issue is that any window opened from a sandbox is given a unique origin.